# Função do sistema para fazer upload de documentos

Tags: php

bom dia pessoal, preciso criar um sistema em php e uma das funções dele é fazer upload de documentos com extensões PDF,WORD, xls... como faço pra criar essa função ???

Comment: André, explique melhor o que você quer, mais detalhes, coloque o que você já tentou, etc.

Comment: Olá, André. Acredito que você quer armazenar estes arquivos para uma pasta  ou local interno. Você poderia tentar utilizando o input type="file" em um form do tipo enctype="multipart/form-data", e faz as tratativas no php. um exemplo você pode encontrar em https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Seria para uma pasta do servidor?

Comment: Se lhe servir posso disponibilizar  http://kithomepage.com/sos/upload_file/upload.html